# Java button reapeating itself

Tags: java

The button listener is stacking: the first time I click the button, it writes in the combo-box once; the second time it writes twice, and so on.

Do I have to clean the buffer or something like that?

```
novoP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      painel.removeAll();
      painel2.removeAll();

      if(autenticator == false) {
         add(painel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         painel.add(nega);
      } else {
         add(painel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         painel.add(iproduto);
         painel.add(buton);

         buton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {                             
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               jComboBox1.addItem(iproduto.getText().toString());
            }
         });
       }
       painel.repaint();
       painel.revalidate();
       painel2.repaint();
       painel2.revalidate();
    }
});
```

Comment: why are you adding button every time in your action listener `painel.add(buton);` ?

Comment: You tell your button to **add** something to a combox box every time its clicked. So, what do you expect to happen when you click that button repeatedly?